# Project a numberDecimal value into a float in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation, projection

I am new to MongoDB and Pymongo, but have learnt some lessons from their Mongo university. I have a nested document, and I would like to only extract specific values from it. I am currently trying to extract the numeric part of PriceEGC but I wasn't successful. My code to construct the projection and extract specific values is shown below:

```
import os
import math
import pymongo
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128

# more code above not shown
for collection in all_collections[:1]:
    first_seen_date = collection.name.split("_")[-1]
    projection = {
        (more projections)...,
        "RegoExpiryDate": "$Vehicle.Registration.Expiry",
        "VIN": "$_id",
        "ComplianceDate": None,
        "PriceEGC": "$Price.FinalDisplayPrice",  # <- this here is the problem
        "Price": None,
        "Reserve": "$Search.IsReservedDate",
        "StartingBid": None,
        "Odometer": "$Vehicle.Odometer",
        (more projections)...
    }

    batch_size = 1
    num_batches = math.ceil(collection.count_documents({}) / batch_size)

    for num in range(1):  # range(num_batches):
        pipeline = [
            {"$match": {}},
            {"$project": projection},
            {"$skip": batch_size * num},
            {"$limit": batch_size},
        ]
        aggregation = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
        yield aggregation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dumps(next(get_all_collections()), indent=2))
```

A typical document looks like this:
[image: typical document]

What I do with the aggregation is I print out this single document, to see what it looks like first, before loading the entire collection somewhere.

The output I don't want is this:

```
[{
(more key-value pairs)...,
"RegoExpiryDate": "2021-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"VIN": "JTMRBREVX0D087618",
"ComplianceDate": null,
"PriceEGC": {
  "$numberDecimal": "36268.00"  # <- Don't want this
},
"Price": null,
"Reserve": null,
"StartingBid": null,
"Odometer": 54567,
(more key-value pairs)...
}]
```

The output I want is this:

```
[{
(more key-value pairs)...,
"RegoExpiryDate": "2021-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
"VIN": "JTMRBREVX0D087618",
"ComplianceDate": null,
"PriceEGC": 36268.00, (or) "PriceEGC": "36268.00",  # <- Want this
"Price": null,
"Reserve": null,
"StartingBid": null,
"Odometer": 54567,
(more key-value pairs)...
}]
```

**How would I write the projection or the pipeline, so that I get what I want, as shown above?** I've tried:

```
projection = {...,
"PriceEGC": "$Price.FinalDisplayPrice.$numberDecimal",
...
}
```

and

```
projection = {...,
"PriceEGC": {"$toDecimal": "$Price.FinalDisplayPrice"}
...
}
```

and

```
projection = {...,
"PriceEGC": Decimal128.to_decimal("$Price.FinalDisplayPrice")
...
}
```

and altering the pipeline as well

```
pipeline = [
    {"$match": {}},
    {"$project": projection},
    {"$toDecimal": "$Price.FinalDisplayPrice"},
    {"$skip": batch_size * num},
    {"$limit": batch_size},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the `bson.json_util()` representation of a MongoDB Decimal128 object. For more information on this data type, see https://www.mongodb.com/developer/quickstart/bson-data-types-decimal128/

The `bson.json_util()` function provides the `$numberDecimal` wrapper so that the data type is preserved should you wish later to load the data back in.

If you want a different behaviour then you might want to use the regular `json.dumps()` and override the Decimal128 behaviour, e.g.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.decimal128 import Decimal128
import json
import bson


class CustomJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bson.decimal128.Decimal128):
            return float(obj.to_decimal())


db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db['mycollection']

collection.insert_one({'Price': {'FinalDisplayPrice': Decimal128('36268.00')}})
print(json.dumps(list(collection.find({}, {'_id': 0})), indent=4, cls=CustomJsonEncoder))
```

prints:

```
[
    {
        "Price": {
            "FinalDisplayPrice": 36268.0
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pattern matching here, but

```
"name": "$name.name.name",
```

seemed to work for

```
"RegoExpiryDate": "$Vehicle.Registration.Expiry",
```

So try the same pattern with `PriceEGC`:

```
    projection = {...
        "PriceEGC": "$Price.FinalDisplayPrice.numberDecimal",
    ...}
```

Comment: This suggestion doesn't work